# In a Postman pre-request-script, how can I read the actual value of a header that uses a variable

Tags: variables, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a variable called `token` with a specific value `myTokenValue`

I try to make a call that includes that variable in a header, `tokenHeader:{{token}}`

I also have a pre-request-script that needs to change the request based on the value of the token header, but if I try to read the value `pm.request.headers.get('tokenHeader')` I get the literal value `{{token}}` instead of the interpolated `myTokenValue`

How do I get this value without having to look at the variable directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I was missing a [function to interpolate a string, injecting variables from the environment](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5767#issue-398435936)

There are some workarounds:

- write your own function, as in [this comment by pomeh](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5767#issuecomment-453946473)

```
function interpolate (value) {
    return value.replace(/{{([^}]+)}}/g, function (match, $1) {
        return pm.variables.get($1);
    });
}
```

- use Postman's own `replaceSubstitutions`, as in [this comment by codenirvana](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2434#issuecomment-485907692)

```
function interpolate (value) {
    const {Property} = require('postman-collection');
    let resolved = Property.replaceSubstitutions(value, pm.variables.toObject());
}
```

Either of these can be used as
`const tokenHeader = interpolate(pm.request.headers.get('tokenHeader'));`
but the second one is also null safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function to replace any Postman variables in a string with their resolved values:

```
var resolveVariables = s => s.replace(/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/g,  
  (match, capture) => pm.variables.get(capture));
```

In your example:

```
var token = resolveVariables(pm.request.headers.get('tokenHeader'));
```